# How to have TS infer a callback in a generic builder function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following use case demo ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEDtQewIwFYFMDGAXUcCuBLANgCZIBOoaAFgIYYqXQDOSeAZgLTFLMlKQpKg409UAGskAT2FZ6OSAHNQlUB2ahmWXmhwxIAKCIo8lDmo3pt0ALaUxAeUQAeANKgkADzQ8Cw%20mmKy5AD4ACl1QcMxcQhIALlBglTjgkTinAEpQAF5A0EgsSzgSDOzQACVUGGICZwAaXPzC4kDdNLjylErqpzq8gpJAgG5dXRBQADkYDGkA0AADFVnMcVyYAHcAOgg8PFA5GBgCOpccYVkuYg4CRWEHACI3W9AAH1Bb8VvA9d0OyF9YRAAjFlQNY7IhgsFijlggBvUBuOIAuriOIAJlAAF80mkhiMwLYYAAHeg9NZkKgYVb8PzLNAwUDSfjzTizI4CU6Qc6Xa6gBy%20fzyT7fHR-eAIdGZEE2JD2BAJThZaFwhGgJGgFHKTjBW4UE6gejkGBYQgrDCFRTbNZIQ6wSB4ZZuWCkcQAQluGSxOOGowAKuQ9atKiISZFKUgAORXVZ0DAuOmYfiULB06xaWjbZZnEiXL4-UWIADMwNBMsc90eLzeH3lqhKsPhiORcRU2oeHuxQyAA)):

```js
// A builder that can self-reference its keys using a ref function
declare function makeObj<K extends string>(
    builder: (ref: (k: K) => number) => Record<K, number>
): Record<K, number>;

// Not using `ref` for now. All good, K is inferred as <"x" | "y">.
const obj1 = makeObj(() => ({ x: 1, y: 2 }));

// Oops, now that we try to use `ref`, K is inferred as <string>.
const obj2 = makeObj(ref => ({ x: 1, y: ref("invalid key, only x or y") }));

// This works, but we'd want K to be automatically inferred.
const obj3 = makeObj<"x" | "y">(ref => ({ x: 1, y: ref("x") }));
```

So, how should I write `makeObj` so `K` is automatically inferred?

Comment: Yuck!  The compiler isn't really able to infer both `K` and the type of `ref` at the same time because of its heuristic approach of a small number of inference phases; without something like [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), these problems will come up.  Unfortunately all of the workarounds I'm trying are not working and something ends up being widened to `unknown` or `string`; and [this bizarre behavior](https://tsplay.dev/wO8R6N) is throwing me.  Sigh.

Comment: Just filed [microsoft/TypeScript#45286](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45286) in case anyone else is trying a similar approach

Comment: Coming back to this: I doubt that what you want is possible, and the best you can do is to manually specify the `K` (as in `obj3`) since it can't be inferred.  Everything I am trying either does not work, or it's crazier than just manually specifying `K`.  I won't write up an answer yet; maybe someone else can find something better?

Comment: Maybe try `const obj2 = makeObj(ref => ({ x: 1, y: ref("invalid key, only x or y") } as const));`

Comment: Please post a link to your implementation of the type also.  A self referencing type is a great idea.

Comment: `let x = {
    firstName: 'Saoirse',
    lastName: 'Ronan',
    age: 26,
  };
  { x = {...x, lastName: \`${x.firstName} ${x.lastName}\`} };`.

It's hard to see how you can make something more convenient than that.  You get typo checking and suggestions as you type in `x. ...`.  Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Try declare `Record<K, number>` as second generic type.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoBrEAeQCMArAHgGl4QAPDEVYAZ3g4xi1QDmAGngAVRizad4AJXA4YweiNTICFEDAB8WgBQAoePArIsEUDABc8XXETXdxa3QCU8ALxb4q9ZreexfRdrUX19MDweeBxqAEYPQhJyal1dfy9dAG94JmtYkQBPawAmeABfFxcAbnDIjGjqUvdE0koqWxBEDwzs3Ph8+CL4O10AIn4ANygILGB4UgKRPAgCnOiYQdG3Cura1CiYqgBmBKJWlLtum168wusR0aYt8sqqoA)

```js
declare function makeObj<K extends string, T extends Record<K, number> = Record<K, number>>(
  builder: (ref: (k: K) => number) => T
): T

const obj1 = makeObj(() => ({ x: 1, y: 2 }));
const obj2 = makeObj(ref => ({ x: 1, y: ref("invalid key, only x or y") }));
const obj3 = makeObj(ref => ({ x: 1, y: ref("x") }));
```

### Limitation

Well, as @kaya3 commented below.
This resolution can only infer the return type.
It still cannot find the invalid key unless explicitly set generic type.

```js
// error will shown when given explicit generic type
const obj2 = makeObj<'x' | 'y'>(ref => ({x: 1, y: ref("invalid key, only x or y")}));
```

Comment: All three of these infer `K` to be `string`.

Comment: @kaya3, Yes, **BUT** the return value type is correctly inferred. That is what we want, right?

Comment: The OP also presumably wants the second example to give an error (because `ref` is supposed to take a parameter of type `K`).

Comment: @kaya3, Oh, I didn't realize it. Let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Ref<Obj> = {
  ref<Key extends string & keyof Obj>
      (k:`${Key}`):Obj[Key]
};

declare function makeObject<Type>(obj: Type): Type & Ref<Type>;


const person = makeObject({
  firstName: "Saoirse",
  lastName: "Ronan",
  age: 26
});

person.ref('firstName') // (method) ref<"firstName">(k: "firstName"): string

// Argument of type '"firstNme"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"firstName" | "lastName" | "age"'.ts(2345)
person.ref('firstNme') // ERROR

person.ref('age') // (method) ref<"age">(k: "age"): number
```

Reference ["String Unions in Types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#string-unions-in-types)

Unfortunately you can't access `ref` when you are declaring the object in the call to `makeObject`.  Fortunately, the native Javascript approximation is pretty good anyway.

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)  Typescript is awesome!